# Poor performance of Spark Cassandra from Kafka using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns
import com.datastax.spark.connector.toRDDFunctions
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
import com.redis.RedisClientPool
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json.parse
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String, dt: String,id: String)
case class historyevent(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String)
object historyData extends Serializable {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

val clients = new RedisClientPool("192.168.0.40", 6379)
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Fleet History Data")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.40")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "20000")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "800M")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "800M")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "1")
  .set("spark.cores.max", "4")
  .set("spark.driver.cores", "1")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val topics = Map(ArrowAssoc("topicname") -> 1)

val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "192.168.0.40:2181", "groupname", topics)

kafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val updatedRDD =
    rdd.map(a =>
      {
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
        val jValue = parse(a._2)
        //  println("value " + jValue.toString())
        val fleetrecord = jValue.extract[historyevent]
        val hash = fleetrecord.imei + fleetrecord.date + fleetrecord.gpsdt
        val md5Hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(hash).toUpperCase()
        val now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())

        event(fleetrecord.imei, fleetrecord.date, fleetrecord.gpsdt, now, md5Hash)

      })
      .collect()

  refArrayOps(updatedRDD).foreach(f =>
    {
      clients.withClient {
        client =>
          {
            val value = f.imei + " , " + f.gpsdt
            val zscore = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
            val key = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
            val dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
            val q1 = "00:00:00"
            val q2 = "06:00:00"
            val q3 = "12:00:00"
            val q4 = "18:00:00"
            val quater = if (augmentString(dt) > q1 && augmentString(dt) < q2) {
              " -> 1"
            } else if (augmentString(dt) > q2 && augmentString(dt) < q3) {
              " -> 2"
            } else if (augmentString(dt) > q3 && augmentString(dt) < q4) {
              " -> 3"
            } else {
              " -> 4"
            }
            client.zadd(key + quater, zscore, value)
          }
      }
    })

  val part = (refArrayOps(updatedRDD).size + 470 - 1) / 470
  val collection = if (part > 0) {
    sc.parallelize(wrapRefArray(updatedRDD), part)
  } else { sc.parallelize(wrapRefArray(updatedRDD)) } 
toRDDFunctions(collection).saveToCassandra("db", "table")

}
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
  }}
```

My hardware specifications:

- 4-node Cassandra cluster

I'm taking a JSON string from Kafka and inserting it into Redis and Cassandra, but this is showing very bad performance. It takes around 1-2 seconds for every one thousand entries upon insertion. For example, for 20K entries, the Spark UI shows it taking around 18-22 seconds. What can be done to tune my performance?

Comment: If you collect the RDD the data is  sent to the driver, operations should be made by the executors.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 - so my code is optimum and no need for optimising ?

Comment: @Pinnacle It means that we should not use `collect()`.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian - Thanks for your help but I need to ask like I'm using collect so that I can push that batch into Cassandra. Since, collect degrades the performance then whats the other way round to achieve this more efficiently ?

Comment: Executors must execute the whole pipeline: read from Kafka, write to Cassandra and write to Redis. Follow the instructions detailed the Cassandra connector https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector and from the Redis connector: https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 - Cassandra worked for me as per your recommendation but Redis is not working and I'm using this library https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis

Comment: That library is not designed to work with Spark. I think you are going to have issues with serialization. Maybe if you declare your client as transient... but, first of all I would try to use the one from RedisLabs

Comment: I tried like this - redisCollection.foreachRDD(rdd =>
      { 
      sc.toRedisZSET(rdd, "hello",("192.168.0.40",6379))
      } ) but gives me an error - Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/JedisClusterCRC16
 at com.redislabs.provider.redis.NodesInfo$.getHost(redisFunctions.scala:128)
 at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisContext.toRedisZSET(redisFunctions.scala:56)

Comment: Also I tried using maven repo <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/RedisLabs/spark-redis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>RedisLabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.2</version>
</dependency>
but it gives error of missing artifact so had to manually download the jar and attach with project.

Comment: Tried one more way - redisCollection.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.foreachPartition(partition => RedisContext.setZset("Hello", partition, 100, redisConfig))
    } so now this gives another error - Symbol 'term <none>.redis.clients' is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by 'method com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisConfig.connectionForKey'. Make sure that term clients is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`. A full rebuild may help if 'RedisConfig.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.redis.